# Twig: How to set title in nested template blocks?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a twig structure like this:

```
{% extends '@layouts/default.html.twig' %}

{% block headerBar %}
    {% include 'partials/my-navigation.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    some content
{% endblock %}
```

But now I have always the same title in my "my-navigation.html.twig".

How can i make it dynamically? maybe something like this:

```
{% extends '@layouts/default.html.twig' %}

{% block myNiceTitle %}
    COOL TITLE 
{% endblock %}

{% block headerBar %}
    {% include 'partials/my-navigation.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    some content
{% endblock %}
```

and then i would use my title in the "my-navigation.html.twig" file dynamically? but how?

I have already read the manual here:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/block.html

but it doenst make me smarter :(

Thx for any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `myNiceTitle` is a block in your navigation template, you could use `embed` and do something like:

```
{% extends '@layouts/default.html.twig' %}

{% block headerBar %}
    {% embed 'partials/my-navigation.html.twig' %}  
        {% block myNiceTitle %}
            COOL TITLE 
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    some content
{% endblock %}
```

And somewhere in `partials/my-navigation.html.twig`:

```
{% block myNiceTitle %}
    DEFAULT TITLE {# or nothing at all... #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: could you also tell me how the syntax should be in my navigation template please? Thx

Comment: @nbg15 I had just added that :-)

Comment: so sorry but this will not give me my COOL TITLE as dynamic title in my navigation twig  (only 'DEFAULT TITLE')

Comment: works fine :) my stupid head was refreshing the wrong page :( thx man!

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable before the include

```
{% set title = 'COOL TITLE' %}

{% block headerBar %}
  {% include 'partials/my-navigation.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then use it inside your include

```
<title>{{ title }}</title>
```

Comment: Thx for your response, but it get this error: Variable "title" does not exist.

Comment: sorry but i still get the errormessage: Variable "title" does not exist.